# How to expand bash array in path like brace expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, glob, brace-expansion

I have the following directory structure

```
./a/unknown.txt
./b/unknown.txt
```

What I want to achieve is

```
cat {a,b}/*.txt
```

The problem is I don't know `a` and `b` in advance but rather I have them in an array like so

```
dirs=(a b)
```

Now, I'm trying `cat ${dirs[@]}/*.txt` but it doesn't work. I have also tried other variations of this without success. The closest I have got is `cat ${dirs[@]/%//*.txt}` but this doesn't expand the `*`. Adding `eval` in the beginning fixes things but I feel there needs to be a more clever way.

I know I can iterate thorugh `dirs` and achieve what I want but I'm not interested in this solution.

Comment: There are no other ways but to use eval.

Comment: Just to note, you could write `cat ${^dirs}/*.txt` in `zsh`. Which is to say, `zsh` provides a *lot* of shortcuts meant for interactive use, but unless you use them *a lot*, they're far less readable than [the loop suggested by @user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682406/1126841).

Answer (score 2):

If you have them in an array, why don't you iterate over the array, which would be clearest:

```
for f in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  cat "$f"/*.txt
done
```

If you really distaste loops (why?) you could do it with a single command:

```
find "${dirs[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'  -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(a b)

shopt -s extglob

ls @(`echo ${dirs[@]} | tr ' ' '|'`)/*
```